# Why can I hear what sounds like a child talking to me on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm doing a multiplayer with a friend. I was near a cave when I heard the usual wind and creepy sounds you hear in the game. But I picked up a word. I realised that there was a voice but all I heard was 'You'. I freaked out and got off the game. I went back on it later that night and I was hiding in my hut (near the same cave, but not enough that I can see it) and I heard what sounded like a child's whine, before it deepened and turned to a creepy, glitchy, evil gurgle. I got off it straight away and my friend hasn't heard it.
EDIT: I can't find any answers anywhere. Also we are using the OZOcraft resource pack, could that be the answer?

Comment: Were you in the overworld or in the Nether? it might have been a ghast, but given that you use a resource pack, it's hard to say.

Comment: disable the resource pack and try again if it's still there

Comment: If you do what dly says but still don't know try looking in the resource pack. Find the sounds folder and play the sounds. It could also help if you recorded it and posted the sound here for us.

Answer (score 3):

## This is caused by your resource pack "OzoCraft"

A quick google search comes up that yes, "OzoCraft" Resource pack adds sounds that can be described "voices". I spent some time and downloaded the resource pack, and looked through it's audio files. It is indeed the ambient cave sounds, precisely 2 to 6.